# How convert a TensorFlow model 2.0 to tslite model with 2.0 API?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

How convert a TensorFlow model 2.0 to tslite model with 2.0 API?

I tried to export my custom `TensorFlow` model to `tflite` format, because I want to integrate this module to an Android application.  I get strange errors after compiling the Python script.

> Used: Tensorflow 2.0.0 beta1 API
>       https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/r2/convert

I tried these methods to convert:

```
 - From SavedModelFrom 
 - tf.Keras Model
```

These points will show in code below.

```py
CipherNeuralModel = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=[20, 20]),
    keras.layers.Dense(400, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(26, activation='softmax')
])

CipherNeuralModel.compile(optimizer='adam',
                          loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                          metrics=['accuracy'])

CipherNeuralModel.fit(trainSumData, imgNumberFromLit, epochs=10, steps_per_epoch=20)

savePath = "D:\FolderToModel"
tf.saved_model.save(CipherNeuralModel, savePath)
export_model = tf.saved_model.load(savePath)
concrete_func = export_model.signatures[
    tf.saved_model.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY
]
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_concrete_functions([concrete_func])
# Error here
converter = converter.convert()


# Example for convert tf.keras model to tflite
# convert_model = tf.function(lambda x: CipherNeuralModel(x))
# concrete_func = convert_model.get_concrete_function(
#     tf.TensorSpec(CipherNeuralModel.inputs[0].shape,
#                   CipherNeuralModel.inputs[0].dtype))
# convertor = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_concrete_functions([concrete_func])
# tflite_model = convertor.convert()
```

> TOCO failed. See console for info.\n%s\n%s\n" % (stdout, stderr))
>   tensorflow.lite.python.convert.ConverterError: TOCO failed. See
>   console for info. b'"toco_from_protos" \xad\xa5
>   \xef\xa2\xab\xef\xa5\xe2\xe1\xef
>   \xa2\xad\xe3\xe2\xe0\xa5\xad\xad\xa5\xa9 \xa8\xab\xa8

Comment: The code is working fine. Can you give your full error log? Also which version of TensorFlow in 2.0 are you using? Can you install the latest version (2.0.0b1) and check. It should work fine.

Comment: I used the latest version."TOCO failed. See console for info.\n%s\n%s\n" % (stdout, stderr))
tensorflow.lite.python.convert.ConverterError: TOCO failed. See console for info.
b'"toco_from_protos" \xad\xa5 \xef\xa2\xab\xef\xa5\xe2\xe1\xef \xa2\xad\xe3\xe2\xe0\xa5\xad\xad\xa5\xa9 \xa8\xab\xa8 \xa2\xad\xa5\xe8\xad\xa5\xa9\r\n\xaa\xae\xac\xa0\xad\xa4\xae\xa9, \xa8\xe1\xaf\xae\xab\xad\xef\xa5\xac\xae\xa9 \xaf\xe0\xae\xa3\xe0\xa0\xac\xac\xae\xa9 \xa8\xab\xa8 \xaf\xa0\xaa\xa5\xe2\xad\xeb\xac \xe4\xa0\xa9\xab\xae\xac.\r\n'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem arise, when library have a long file path(more 255 character). To solve this problem need make next points:

1. Export model to file:

   ```
   savePath = "D:\FolderToModel"
   tf.saved_model.save(CipherNeuralModel, savePath)
   ```
2. Download model to your google drive
3. Make a project in https://colab.research.google.com
4. Connect your google drive to project:

   ```
   from google.colab import drive
   drive.mount('/content/drive')
   ```
5. Import tensorflow library to project:

   ```
   pip install tensorflow==2.0.0-rc0
   ```
6. Import your model from file in google drive and convert it to tensorflow lite model:

   ```
   path = '/content/drive/My Drive/highModelNeural'
   export_model = tf.saved_model.load(path)
   concrete_func = export_model.signatures[
       tf.saved_model.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY
   ]
   converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_concrete_functions([concrete_func])
   converter = converter.convert()
   ```
7. Import your tensorflow lite model to file, which will be created in google drive:

   ```
   open("/content/drive/My Drive/highModelNeural/model70v5.tflite", "wb").write(converter)
   ```

After that, you can use TFlite model in your android application or embedded device.